# How to make CircleLayout in Android by using LetterAdapter

Tags: android

I'll make a small app regarding displaying all alphabet letters circularly and some features related with it. What I want to do is to be specified below and All I did before was also specified .

-> I created a LetterAdapter class for displaying the process (From A to Z) but I have no idea how I can display them circularly. Which circlelayout should I use it?

-> I created a next button. When I press it, the background of next letter is changed and the background of former letter is returned the default color. How can I do it?

-> I also created a textview to display letter expect for circlelayout. the role of next button is used for changing letter (For example B -> C)

Here is my sample design shown as a link below.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZxxi.png)

How can I do the whole process?

Thank you.

Comment: please upload the image here, not an external link.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Exactly... What did you try?

Comment: @Amin Keshavarzian I did what you did.

Comment: @David García Bodego I'm stuck to determine which circlelayout do I use to usemy adapter in the layout. Also, How can I do the next process in circlelayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by animation where you need to create drawable xml where you have to do like

```xml
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="2"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
```

For more you can check this link it will more help full for you https://github.com/andreilisun/Circular-Layout